# How to solve warning 'Use of $this in global code might be unatendedPHP(PHP0437)' when layouting view in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, this, codeigniter-4

I'm still beginner in codeigniter. I try to layouting template (dinamic page) with view layout in codeigniter 4. But all of code

```
$this
```

have warning that says

> Use of $this in global code might be unatendedPHP(PHP0437)

The web still running cause its just yellow warning, not red. But can anyone explain me with this warning and how to solve it? Thank you so much for your response.

This is my template code which named 'default.php':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- <title>Amalia House of Muslimah &mdash; HOM</title> -->
    <?= $this->renderSection('title') ?>

    <!-- General CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/modules/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">

    <!-- CSS Libraries -->

    <!-- Template CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/components.css">
    <!-- Start GA -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-94034622-3"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-94034622-3');
    </script>
    <!-- /END GA -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="main-wrapper main-wrapper-1">
            <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-navbar">
                <form class="form-inline mr-auto">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-3">
                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="sidebar" class="nav-link nav-link-lg"><i
                                    class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="search" class="nav-link nav-link-lg d-sm-none"><i
                                    class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- SEARCH START -->
                    <div class="search-element">
                        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"
                            data-width="250">
                        <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                        <div class="search-backdrop"></div>
                        <div class="search-result">
                            <div class="search-header">
                                Histories
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">How to hack NASA using CSS</a>
                                <a href="#" class="search-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">Kodinger.com</a>
                                <a href="#" class="search-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">#Stisla</a>
                                <a href="#" class="search-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-header">
                                Result
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="mr-3 rounded" width="30" src="assets/img/products/product-3-50.png"
                                        alt="product">
                                    oPhone S9 Limited Edition
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="mr-3 rounded" width="30" src="assets/img/products/product-2-50.png"
                                        alt="product">
                                    Drone X2 New Gen-7
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="mr-3 rounded" width="30" src="assets/img/products/product-1-50.png"
                                        alt="product">
                                    Headphone Blitz
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-header">
                                Projects
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="search-icon bg-danger text-white mr-3">
                                        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Stisla Admin Template
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="search-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="search-icon bg-primary text-white mr-3">
                                        <i class="fas fa-laptop"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    Create a new Homepage Design
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- SEARCH END -->
                </form>
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- MESSAGES START -->
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-list-toggle"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            class="nav-link nav-link-lg message-toggle beep"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right">
                            <div class="dropdown-header">Messages
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <a href="#">Mark All As Read</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-list-content dropdown-list-message">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-avatar">
                                        <img alt="image" src="assets/img/avatar/avatar-1.png" class="rounded-circle">
                                        <div class="is-online"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>Kusnaedi</b>
                                        <p>Hello, Bro!</p>
                                        <div class="time">10 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-avatar">
                                        <img alt="image" src="assets/img/avatar/avatar-2.png" class="rounded-circle">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>Dedik Sugiharto</b>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                                        <div class="time">12 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-avatar">
                                        <img alt="image" src="assets/img/avatar/avatar-3.png" class="rounded-circle">
                                        <div class="is-online"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>Agung Ardiansyah</b>
                                        <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                        <div class="time">12 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-avatar">
                                        <img alt="image" src="assets/img/avatar/avatar-4.png" class="rounded-circle">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>Ardian Rahardiansyah</b>
                                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit ess</p>
                                        <div class="time">16 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-avatar">
                                        <img alt="image" src="assets/img/avatar/avatar-5.png" class="rounded-circle">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>Alfa Zulkarnain</b>
                                        <p>Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
                                        <div class="time">Yesterday</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                                <a href="#">View All <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- MESSAGES END -->

                    <!-- NOTIF START -->
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-list-toggle"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            class="nav-link notification-toggle nav-link-lg beep"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right">
                            <div class="dropdown-header">Notifications
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <a href="#">Mark All As Read</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-list-content dropdown-list-icons">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-icon bg-primary text-white">
                                        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        Template update is available now!
                                        <div class="time text-primary">2 Min Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-icon bg-info text-white">
                                        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>You</b> and <b>Dedik Sugiharto</b> are now friends
                                        <div class="time">10 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-icon bg-success text-white">
                                        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        <b>Kusnaedi</b> has moved task <b>Fix bug header</b> to <b>Done</b>
                                        <div class="time">12 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-icon bg-danger text-white">
                                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        Low disk space. Let's clean it!
                                        <div class="time">17 Hours Ago</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-icon bg-info text-white">
                                        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-item-desc">
                                        Welcome to Stisla template!
                                        <div class="time">Yesterday</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                                <a href="#">View All <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- NOTIF END -->

                    <!-- USER START -->
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-lg nav-link-user">
                            <img alt="image" src="assets/img/avatar/avatar-1.png" class="rounded-circle mr-1">
                            <div class="d-sm-none d-lg-inline-block">Hi, Amalia</div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <div class="dropdown-title">Logged in 5 min ago</div>
                            <a href="features-profile.html" class="dropdown-item has-icon">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i> Profile
                            </a>
                            <a href="features-activities.html" class="dropdown-item has-icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i> Activities
                            </a>
                            <a href="features-settings.html" class="dropdown-item has-icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Settings
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger">
                                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- USER END -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="main-sidebar sidebar-style-2">
                <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <div class="sidebar-brand row row-cols-1">
                        <div class="col">
                            <img src="/assets/img/logo/logo.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" style="line-height: 20px;">
                            <a href="<?=site_url()?>" class="col" style="color: #ff3d87;">A M A L I A</a><br>
                            <a href="<?=site_url()?>" class="col">House of Muslimah</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ??-->
                    <div class="sidebar-brand sidebar-brand-sm">
                        <a href="<?=site_url()?>">St</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ?? -->
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="<?= $menu == 'dashboard' ? 'active' : ''?>"><a class="nav-link"
                                href="<?=site_url()?>"><i class="fas fa-fire"></i>
                                <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown <?= $menu == 'manage' ? 'active' : ''?>">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i
                                    class="fa fa-clipboard-list"></i> <span>Manage</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="nav-link <?= $submenu == 'manageusers' ? 'active' : ''?>"
                                        href="<?=site_url('manage_users')?>">Manage Users</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link <?= $submenu == 'manageevents' ? 'active' : ''?>"
                                        href="<?=site_url('manage_events')?>">Manage Events</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link <?= $submenu == 'managesantriwati' ? 'active' : ''?>"
                                        href="<?=site_url('manage_santriwati')?>">Manage Santriwati</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="<?= $menu == 'jamaah' ? 'active' : ''?>"><a class="nav-link"
                                href="<?=site_url('jamaah')?>"><i class="fa fa-mosque"></i>
                                <span>Jama'ah</span></a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown <?= $menu == 'laporansantriwati' ? 'active' : ''?>">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                                <span>Laporan Santriwati</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="nav-link <?= $submenu == 'pelanggaran' ? 'active' : ''?>"
                                        href="<?=site_url('pelanggaran')?>">Pelanggaran</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link <?= $submenu == 'prestasi' ? 'active' : ''?>"
                                        href="<?=site_url('prestasi')?>">Prestasi</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link <?= $submenu == 'raportpenilaian' ? 'active' : ''?>"
                                        href="<?=site_url('raport_penilaian')?>">Raport Penilaian</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- BUTTON START -->
                    <!-- <div class="mt-4 mb-4 p-3 hide-sidebar-mini">
                        <a href="https://getstisla.com/docs" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-icon-split">
                            <i class="fas fa-rocket"></i> Documentation
                        </a>
                    </div> -->
                    <!-- BUTTON END -->
                </aside>
            </div>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="main-content">
                <?= $this->renderSection('content') ?>
            </div>
            <footer class="main-footer">
                <div class="footer-left">
                    Copyright &copy; 2023 <div class="bullet"></div> Design By <a
                        href="https://chalathadoa.github.io/">Udkhul Rogodan</a>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-right">
                    v1.0
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- General JS Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/modules/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/modules/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/modules/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/modules/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/modules/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/modules/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/stisla.js"></script>

    <!-- JS Libraies -->

    <!-- Page Specific JS File -->

    <!-- Template JS File -->
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my view home named 'viewhome.php'

```
<?= $this->extend('layout/default') ?>

<?= $this->section('title') ?>
<title>Home | Amalia House of Muslimah</title>
<?= $this->endSection() ?>

<?= $this->section('content') ?>
<section class="section">
    <div class="section-header">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="section-body">
    </div>
</section>
<?= $this->endSection() ?>
```

in the tutorial I watched, it seems there's no problem with

```
Sthis
```

code. Here's the tutorial I've watched.[text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlT5fEPhmBI&list=PLTagRbmJ8etv3nFxxR0rjCiWazwGn5Yuo&index=5). Thank you so much for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

This warning seems to be generated by a specific code analyzer.

To tell your analyzer/linter/whatever that `$this` is fine in this context, prepend a doc-block to your view files:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @var CodeIgniter\View\View $this
*/
?>
```

Comment: Glad i could help :) consider marking my answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

type this on setting.json :

```
"php.problems.exclude": {
    "/": [437],
    "vendor/": true
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).